# Flex: How to animate the target I've clicked on?

Tags: apache-flex, animation, flex4, flex-spark

I wrote a loop that adds a MouseEVENT.CLICK event listener to all of the images in my view.

(this part works)

```
var numChildren:int = PageScroll.numChildren; 

for (var i:int = 0; i < numChildren; i++) { 
    if(PageScroll.getChildAt(i) is Image)
    { 
        PageScroll.getChildAt(i).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
    }
}
```

Now I want the onClick play an animation on the target I've clicked on...

I don't know how to do it and can't find it through google....

```
protected function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    maxSize.play(new Array(event.target), false);
}
```

(this part doesn't work)

Comment: Use `currentTarget`. Also note that if you're using Flex 4 containers (as your tags indicate) you probably should be using `getElement` instead of `getChild`. And if this is a list of images, you seem to be reinventing the wheel: a `List` component is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code; this 'll help you...

```
<mx:Canvas id="can" width="500" height="500">
        <mx:Image source="indian cricket logo.png"/>
</mx:Canvas>
<mx:Resize id="resize" widthBy="50" heightBy="50" duration="500"/>


protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i< can.numChildren;i++){
            if(can.getChildAt(i) as Image){
                        Image(can.getChildAt(i)).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onMouseCLick,false,0,true);
                  }
          }

    }

private function onMouseCLick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    resize.play([e.currentTarget]);
}
```